# Can I pass an array from php to xslt contains?

Tags: php, arrays, xslt

I am using the following variable in php to handle a customer id:

```
$k='160177'
```

which I pass to my xslt using:

```
...
$xsl = $proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$xsl = $proc->setParameter('', 'k', $k);
$newdom = $proc->transformToDoc($inputdom);
print $newdom->saveXML();
```

I pick up the variable in my XSLT and use it to check a node:

```
...
<xsl:apply-templates select="td:Globale_Pauschale[contains(td:CreatedBy, $k]">
```

This works fine BUT now I need to pass multiple customer ids via my php variable:

```
$k='160177,160176,160184,160178,160179....etc'
```

And get my XSLT contains statement to check against EACH customer id.

In PHP I would change my $k to an array and iterate through it but XSLT has no concept of an array. How do I get XSLT contains to check against EACH customer id ?

Mayn thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please give us an example of the content of td:CreatedBy. Is this single id?

Comment: td:CreatedBy is a single id stored in xml file. For example: 160177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing to do is to change the order of the contain function call to  `"td:Globale_Pauschale[contains($k,td:CreatedBy)]"`. Than you can have an list of ids in variable k (`$k='160177,160176,160184,160178,160179'`).

But this will only work reliable if the ids have always the same length. (This will not work if you have also shorter ids like `16`).

To make this work for ids with different length use the following select:

```
select="td:Globale_Pauschale[contains($k, 
            concat(',', normalize-space(td:CreatedBy), ','))]"
```

and put an comma at front and end of your variable k.
`$k=',160177,160176,160184,160178,160179,16,'`

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Works a treat!

Comment: @RichardTinkler: Glad I could help. Please consider to mark the answer as accepted. If you do not know how, have a look to [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).